# Support needed for looping my code

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Can someone please help me how to loop my function ? 
here is my code i just want that my will execute more times than only one. 
I have already tried to create my own for loop, but it doesnt work.
Hope someone is so friendly to help me out with my problem and can give little bit explain about how to get rid of my problem with loops.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     for (var i = 1; i<=4; i++){
        windows.open(i);
     }
     function MultiplyLinks(){
        window.open("#")
        window.open("#")
        window.open("#")
     }
    </script>
    <title>Javascript MultiplyLinks Opener</title>


</head>
<body>
<a h ref ="javascript:MultiplyLinks()">Open More links</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Well guys thanks . I 've got the problem. 
i have used windows.open(i);

but it has to be MultiplyLinks(i);
otherwise it will never recognize my function.
i just wanted that my 3 links will executed more times and that works for now.
Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: What is `windows.open(i)` supposed to achieve? Maybe you meant `window.open(someUrl)` (without the final `s` and passing something other than a number).

Comment: Be careful with the extra space in `<a h ref` (between H and REF).

Answer (score 2):

Few issues:
1) you've got a typos
change

```
windows.open(i)
```

to

```
window.open(i)
```

2) Why are you trying to open i rather than use a url?
suggest you change i to something more meaningful like:

```
window.open('http://someusr');
```

3) you have a space in the anchor tag :
  change

```
  <a h ref=
```

to

```
<a href=
```

so the final code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     for (var i = 1; i<=4; i++){
        window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
     }
     function MultiplyLinks(){
        window.open("#")
        window.open("#")
        window.open("#")
     }
    </script>
    <title>Javascript MultiplyLinks Opener</title>


</head>
<body>
<a href ="javascript:MultiplyLinks()">Open More links</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But again, what is passing a number as an URL to `window.open()` supposed to achieve in the first place?

Comment: I have no idea Frederic..that is something I leave to him to figure out :) i'm assumig he just put the number in there in general..but thank's I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var links   = [
    'http://jquery.com',
    'http://stackoverflow.com/',
    'https://bitbucket.org',
    'https://github.com'
];

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    window.open( links[i] );
}
```